# leave transition does not work when ngIf is on parent component

Tags: angular, animation

I have a very simple component with a fade in/out animation :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      state('void', 
        style({
          opacity: 0
        })
      ),
       transition(':enter, :leave',[
          animate(2000)
        ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class TooltipComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Here is the associated template :

```
<div @fade>
  This is my tooltip
</div>
```

Here is how the component is called :

```
<button (click)="show = !show">Show Tooltip</button>
<app-tooltip *ngIf="show"></app-tooltip>
```

the entering animation is working very well, but the leaving one doesn't. If I put the ngIf in the tooltip component, both animations works but it is not a wanted solution. Indeed, my tooltip component is a component which is already exist in a self made library which is already used in a lot of project in my company. I don't want to modify all library's client project (except the version of the library). My goal is to easily add an animation on all tooltip.

Here is my problem on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wanrsx

Can someone explain me why my leaving animation does not work please ? How can I make both animation works without moving my ngif directive ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23302) about this.

The proposed workaround is placing a dummy-animation on the parent div, which triggers the child animation with animateChild().

In your case this would be: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxywae

**General Implementation:**

Animation:

```
trigger('blub', [
  transition('* => void', [
    query("@*", [animateChild()], {optional: true})
  ]),
])
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="showing" [@blub]>
  <div [@bla] style="background: blue; width: 200px; height: 50px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, the reason why your fade-out animation is not working is because the animation is inside `<app-tooltip></app-tooltip>`. When the button is clicked, the `*ngIf` hides the tooltip, disregarding the animation that is happening inside of `<app-tooltip></app-tooltip>`.

However, simply moving the animation outside shows some weird behaviour:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaqbg4

The Tool-tip is shown immediately, and when clicked again, the Tool-tip disappears after 2 seconds, without any fade-out animation.

I cant explain this, but I am guessing it has to do with how angular handles components differently from other elements when removing them from the view.

To fix this, we can simply move the animation into a wrapper div: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqnxzn

Comment: fixing this problem moving animation into a wrapper div is not a solution for me. As I said, my tooltip is in a library and I don't want to change all projects which use the tooltip component to integrate this new animation. I would like to implement all the animation in the component without changing any code in the way I call it. Maybe it's not possible but I would like to undestand what in the angular lifecyle make it impossible.

Comment: Iam assuming that, since the component itself has no animation, when the `ngIf` evaluates to false and destroys the component (removing it from DOM) it will just hide it and not play the animation. The animation that you see in the beginning is happening because the component is created (loaded into DOM) and it loads the div for the first time. Apart from that, I find it unusal that a component would prevent itself from being immediately removed from DOM when a `ngIf` wants to remove it. Obviously wouldnt be a problem if the component was still up, with only the div being hidden.

Comment: For information. I found an opened issue on angular tracker about that : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23302

Comment: Ah, good job on finding that. To be honest I kind of expect this behavior, since I'd usually want control over how to animate external components in my application. I can see why it would be wanted in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still exists in Angular 15.0.4.

My way out is to use the method of adding a dummy animation to the parent but without changing the outer HTML code.
This can be done using HostBinding which enables us to change the main component tag from inside the component code.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      state('void', 
        style({
          opacity: 0
        })
      ),
       transition(':enter, :leave',[
          animate(2000)
        ])
    ]),
    /*Dummy animation*/
    trigger('blub', [
      transition('* => void', [
        query("@*", [animateChild()], { optional: true })
      ]),
    ])
  ]
})
export class TooltipComponent {

  /*Add dummy animation*/
  @HostBinding('@blub') null;

  constructor() { }
}
```